# Bash: check multiple definitions to if

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I need check the variable $1 if equal to multiple definitions, this script work:

```
 if [ "$1" == "demo" ]; then
            echo hello
 else
 ...
```

Instead this don't work:

```
 if [[ "$1" == "demo" && "$1" == "prod" ]]; then
            echo hello
 else
 ...
```

If i put `demo` or `prod`, the script is bypassed

Comment: Don't use `==` with `[`. Either use `=`, or switch to `[[`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$1` can not be "demo" and "prod" at the same time. You have to use || (or)

```
if [[ "$1" == "demo" || "$1" == "prod" ]]; then
```